# Difference of countable union included in the countable union of difference?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $G=\bigcup_{i=1}^{+\infty} G_i$ be a countable union of open sets, and $E=\bigcup_{i=1}^{+\infty} E_i$ be a countable union of measurable sets such that $G_i\supseteq E_i$ for every $i$. Then, my textbok says: $$G-E=\bigcup_{i=1}^{+\infty} G_i-\bigcup_{i=1}^{+\infty} E_i\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^{+\infty} (G_i-E_i).$$

Could anybody please explain to me why: $$\bigcup_{i=1}^{+\infty} G_i-\bigcup_{i=1}^{+\infty} E_i\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^{+\infty} (G_i-E_i).$$

I just don't get it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in\bigcup_iG_i-\bigcup_iE_i$. Then there is an $i\in\Bbb N$ with $x\in G_i$, and for all $j\in\Bbb N,x\notin E_j$. Note that to have $x\in\bigcup_i(G_i-E_i)$ we need there to exist an $i\in\Bbb N$ such that $x\in G_i$ and $x\notin E_i$. But $x\in G_i$ is already given, and $x\notin E_j$ for all $j$ so in particular $x\notin E_i$.

The propositional analogue of this law says

$$(\exists x\,P(x)\land\neg\exists x\,Q(x))\iff\exists x(P(x)\land\forall y\,\neg Q(y))\implies\exists x(P(x)\land\neg Q(x)).$$